# Laravel BootstrapVue CRUD SPA how to make an Accesor that affect only one vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, crud, edit

Im building a CRUD SPA with it a model that uses mutator accessor to change a couple of data  attributes from INT to readable characters and have the data displayed on a table component.

Example

```
class TradingModel extends Model
{
public function getTradingStatusIdAttribute($attribute)
    {
        return [
            0 => 'trading status 1',
            1 => 'trading status 2',

        ][$attribute];
    }
}
```

And uses a bootsrap-vue component to edit the values.
But with the mutated values I need to edit all the fields to make sure I save the right datatype attributes to the DB.

```
   <template>

        <b-form-select id="sales_status_id"
               v-model="form.sales_status_id">
               <option :value="0">trading status 1</option>
               <option value="1">trading status 2</option>

        </b-form-select>


  </template>

  <script>
  data() {
  return {
    items: [],

     form: {
      property_name: '',
      address: '',
      trading_status_id: '',
      sale_priority_id: '',
      sales_status_id: '',
  }
```

What are the approaches and solution to this situation.
Is it possible to use accessor to only one component?
Or how can I get the original values from the db and bypass the mutated values.

Thank you in advance, Im learning and and teaching my self to code and still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to rodrogo.pedra

You can have a virtual accessor for the values label:

```
class TradingModel extends Model
{
    // tells Laravel to append this virtual column to JSON output
    protected $appends = ['trading_status_label'];

    public function getTradingStatusLabelAttribute()
    {
        return [
            0 => 'trading status 1',
            1 => 'trading status 2',
        ][$this->trading_status_id];
    }
}
```

Think of vue's computed property, but for Laravel.

This way you can use trading_status_label for display in the table and keep using trading_status_id original value in forms or data related tasks.